# Why does scikit-learns RMSE scorer function return the MSE?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was confused about scores of a model which I evaluated and noticed that the score function in the RMSE scorer actually returns the MSE, although with `make_scorer` it gets passed the keyword `squared=False` which should equal to RMSE.
It can be seen seen [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ce89a4ff155cf1ec06e991a2910ca3b3c0224394/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py#L706).

Minimal example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import get_scorer
x = [1, 1, 1]
y = [1, 3, 3]
get_scorer('neg_root_mean_squared_error')._score_func(x, y) == get_scorer('neg_mean_squared_error')._score_func(x, y)
```

returns `True`.

I understand that the scorer object is mainly used for training, where the scaling factor of taking the sqrt does not make a difference, however if one wants to show the actual scores it seems misleading to show the MSE but have a RMSE-named scorer.

I tested this using scikit-learn 1.2.0 as well as 0.23.

Are scorers not intended to be used by accessing `_score_func` directly or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_score_func` only contains the function. What makes the difference is the named argument here.

You should be able to make it work your way with a minor modificaton:

```
scorer1 = get_scorer('neg_root_mean_squared_error')
scorer2 = get_scorer('neg_mean_squared_error')
scorer1._score_func(x, y, **scorer1._kwargs) == scorer2._score_func(x, y, **scorer2._kwargs)
```

You probably should not access it like that unless absolutely needed, since you're just calling `mean_squared_error()` in an ugly way.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks! I thought the score function is already initialized properly when calling `get_scorer()` and didn't know about passing the scorer args.